# I want to move 1 array to another in C#

Tags: c#, arrays

This is just a quick question in C#.

I have a scenario where I am working with several devices that all have slightly different data to work with.

When I work out which device I am using, I want to set up a common array to use throughout the code, say arrayCommon.

So I want to move the info from device1 to the common array.

Do I have to do this in a loop for each occurance in the array or can u move the whole array into the common array, as you could in Cobol all those years ago ?

Thanks, George.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you are looking for that : [Array.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.copy%28VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Just a note, if you are needing it in a performance critical section of code, rather use:

```
Buffer.BlockCopy()
```

[Link here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.buffer.blockcopy.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Array array = new char["String".Length];
 "String".ToCharArray().CopyTo(array, 0);
```